# Почему до сих пор нету ИИ? Ведь по идее вычислительная мощность суперкомпьютеров гораздо выше чем у одного единственного человеческого мозга

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

То есть даже без создания специального железа это должно быть возможно в софте. Мне всё это кажется очень странным.

Comment: "Весь человеческий мозг содержит 86 миллиардов нейронов", я бы не сказал, что такое количество нейронов (и связей между ними!) можно моделировать на современных суперкомпьютерах. Ещё пахать и пахать до этого, так что есть и чисто количественные проблемы, даже если не рассматривать качественные.

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых, мы просто не знаем сами, как именно мыслим (поэтому ничего подобного не можем изобразить), а во-вторых (imho) вы недооцениваете мощность мозга.

Насколько мне известно, попытки полного моделирования поведения нематоды (всего 302 нейрона) все еще не достигли результата (поведение модели червя и живого отличаются).

Вероятно, это следствие того, что моделируемые нейроны менее динамичны (в них не моделируется экспрессия генов при изменении среды), чем реальные.